# GROUP BY two fields in mysql

Tags: mysql, group-by

I have a table in mysql  where it stores the messages between users.
  The Table has the following fields:

```
ID   from_memberID  to_memberID   message                 Date
+----+--------------+------------+-----------------------+-----------------------+
1         205          207         hello Peter           19/08/2012 20:00:00
2         207          205         Hi frank              19/08/2012 20:01:00
3         205          208         hello Jennifer        19/08/2012 20:10:00
4         207          210         hello Peter           19/08/2012 20:20:00
```

Well, let's suppose I want to get only last message from each conversation by user 205

it should get registers 2 and 3, the conversation between users(205-207) and users (205-208). The fact is that i use GROUP BY from_memberID and then in my result the register ID=1 is added too.

This is the statement is use:

```
SELECT *
FROM
(SELECT msg.ID,
    msg.mensaje,
    msg.from_miembroID,
    msg.fecha,
    msg.read,
    FROM mensajes as msg
    INNER JOIN miembros as mem ON mem.ID=IF(msg.from_miembroID=205, msg.to_miembroID, msg.from_miembroID)
WHERE msg.to_miembroID=205 OR msg.from_miembroID=205
ORDER BY msg.fecha DESC) as temp
GROUP BY from_miembroID
```

how can i use GROUP BY for considering the two columns (from_memberID, to_memberID) to be as one?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: @Marc B Thanks for the corretion

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You could use a new custom field, ordering the ids (`from_memberID`, `to_memberID`) by a custom rule, e.g. the smaller one always comes first.

For example:

```
SELECT 
     IF(from_memberID < to_memberID, 
         CONCAT(from_memberID, '-', to_memberID),
         CONCAT(to_memberID, '-', from_memberID)
     ) as conversation_ids
FROM `messages`
```

That field will return unique combinations, e.g. 205-207 no matter if 205 sent a message to 207 or 207 sent a message to 207.

Finally, you could group by this value and get unique combinations.

Comment: This works but, Well I think this is not giving us the latest message or id of the message shared between the users. GROUP BY conversation_ids returns only the first message exchanged between the users, not the latest one. please help

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you simply join the members and messages tables on ID and keep only the ones with from_miembroID = 205 and to_miembroID = 205 and then union the results:

```
SELECT * FROM(
SELECT msg.ID,
       msg.mensaje,
       msg.from_miembroID as user,
       msg.fecha,
       msg.read,
FROM mensajes as msg INNER JOIN miembros as mem ON mem.ID=msg.from_miembroID
WHERE msg.from_miembroID=205
UNION
SELECT msg.ID,
       msg.mensaje,
       msg.from_miembroID,
       msg.fecha,
       msg.read,
FROM mensajes as msg INNER JOIN miembros as mem ON mem.ID=msg.to_miembroID
WHERE msg.to_miembroID=205
)
ORDER BY msg.date
LIMIT 1
```

Comment: ok, and how can i get the last message from each conversation?

Comment: @Razvan How do you know for sure that the last message is selected? Also, I believe `UNION` shows only the first record found with the same values and message `id` is different.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, hope I understood it right, what you want. I would first select every message that is from or to the current user (ID=205) like this:

```
SELECT * FROM mensajes
WHERE (from_memberID=205 OR to_memberID=205)
```

Now we want to group conversations together, which means by the ID of the user thats not having ID=205. We can achieve this by using an IF statement.
IF works this way: **IF(condition,value-if-true,value-if-false)**. So we create a virtual column **otherID**, which contains the conversation partner userid:
`IF(from_memberID=205,to_memberID,from_memberID) AS otherID`. Then the SQL looks like this:

```
SELECT 
  ID,
  IF(from_memberID=205,to_memberID,from_memberID) AS otherID,
  message,
  Date
FROM mensajes
WHERE (from_memberID=205 OR to_memberID=205)
```

Now we just need to add a `GROUP BY otherID` and an `ORDER BY Date` (last posting is kept in a group):

```
SELECT 
  ID,
  IF(from_memberID=205,to_memberID,from_memberID) AS otherID,
  message,
  Date
FROM mensajes
WHERE (from_memberID=205 OR to_memberID=205)
GROUP BY otherID
ORDER BY Date
```

Now we can join this together with the table `miembros` using the SQL above as a subselect:

```
SELECT * FROM
    (SELECT 
      ID,
      IF(from_memberID=205,to_memberID,from_memberID) AS otherID,
      message,
      Date
    FROM mensajes
    WHERE (from_memberID=205 OR to_memberID=205)
    GROUP BY otherID
    ORDER BY Date) AS last
INNER JOIN miembros as mem ON mem.ID=lastotherID;
```